# Переадресация запросов на другой сайт

Tags: django

мне поставили задачу, чтобы шла переадресация на другой сайт и выводились готовые ответы с указанными требованиями.
К примеру, у меня на сайте вбивают, что дата тура или перелета с 10.06.23 по 23.07.23, бюджет, геолокация и тд, а далее нужна переадресация на другой сайт, где подбираются эти критерии (турвизор). Подскажите как это сделать, пишу сайт на Django

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Через запросы к API турвизора, если он есть.